# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll' in a web scraper

Tags: python

I am making a program for web scraping but this is my first time. The tutorial that I am using is built for python 2.7, but I am using 3.8.2. I have mostly edited my code to fit it to python 3, but one error pops up and I can't fix it.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.showmeboone.com/sheriff/JailResidents/JailResidents.asp'


response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(features="html.parser")

results_table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'resultsTable'})

output = []


for row in results_table.findAll('tr'):


    output_rows = []

    for cell in tr.findAll('td'):

        output_rows.append(cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', ''))


    output.append(output_rows)



print(output)

handle = open('out-using-requests.csv', 'a')
outfile = csv.writer(handle)
outfile.writerows(output)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\scrape.py", line 17, in <module>
    for row in results_table.findAll('tr'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

The tutorial I am using is https://first-web-scraper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I tried some other questions, but they didn't help.

Please help!!!

Edit: Never mind, I got a good answer.

Comment: What is the issue, how do you interpret that error? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` returns `None` if it doesn't find a match. You need to check for that before attempting to find any sub elements in it:

```py
results_table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'resultsTable'})
output = []

if results_table:
    for row in results_table.findAll('tr'):
        output_rows = []

        for cell in tr.findAll('td'):

            output_rows.append(cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', ''))


        output.append(output_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error allows the following conclusion:

```
results_table = None
```

Therefore, you cannot access the `findAll()` method because `None.findAll()` does not exist.

You should take a look, it is best to use a debugger to run through your program and see how the variables change line by line and why the mentioned line only returns ```None''. Especially important is the line:

```
results_table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'resultsTable'})
```

Because in this row results_table is initialized yes, so here the above `none'' value is returned and`results_table'' is assigned.